# Se requiere un objeto

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, datatables, vba, condiciones

Hice un userform y para validar las cajas de textos puse un IF, el tema es que me sale error (imagen adjunta). No sé como crear el objeto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD. Tengo conectada la base de datos a excel y cuando genero las consultas sin el IF trae resultado exitoso, pero cuando dejo el IF me pide el objeto.

**CODIGO**:

```
 ' RUT IS NOT NULL, PERIODO IS NULL, CONTRATO IS NULL
 If Me.txtQuery.Value Is Not Null And Me.txtQuery3.Value Is Null And Me.txtQuery2.Value Is Null Then
 With Me

    ConsultaSQL = "SELECT  PeriodoCarga PERIODO, RUT, DV, CUSTAC CUENTA, NOMBRE, TIPOCLIENTE," & _
                  "SEGCLI SEGMENTO,CLASIFRIESGO RIESGO, NumeroOper CONTRATO," & _
                  "TipoProductoSigir PRODUCTO, Filler11 CARTERA," & _
                  "DIAMORA DIAS_MORA, MONEDA, MontoColocTotal COLOCACIÓN," & _
                  "TasaInteres TASA_INTERES, MontoProvCont PROV_CONT," & _
                  "MontoProvEFEC PROV_EFEC,MontoProvTotal PROV_TOT, [%Provision]" & _
                  "FROM dbo.b_prv000_formatoNvo " & _
                  "where rut = " & Me.txtQuery.Value
 End With
 End If
```

Comment: Te toca mostrar el código que genera eso. COMO TEXTO. Por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta. :P

Comment: listo :') helpme pls

Comment: Ya intentó depurar? Cando hace click en "Depurar" ¿A cuaál línea lo envía? Parece que es una variable que no se ha instanciado, o que no es de tipo Object.

Comment: Lo mejor es que pongas algún punto de interrupción en tu código y así ir viendo línea a linea la declaración y valores de las variables. Al parecer te falta instanciar algo y en ese código que pones no lo podemos seguir, para saber de donde se inicia.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' RUT IS NOT NULL, PERIODO IS NULL, CONTRATO IS NULL
     If Not IsNull(Me.txtQuery.Value) And IsNull(Me.txtQuery3.Value) And IsNull(Me.txtQuery2.Value) Then
         With Me
        
            ConsultaSQL = "SELECT  PeriodoCarga PERIODO, RUT, DV, CUSTAC CUENTA, NOMBRE, TIPOCLIENTE," & _
                          "SEGCLI SEGMENTO,CLASIFRIESGO RIESGO, NumeroOper CONTRATO," & _
                          "TipoProductoSigir PRODUCTO, Filler11 CARTERA," & _
                          "DIAMORA DIAS_MORA, MONEDA, MontoColocTotal COLOCACIÓN," & _
                          "TasaInteres TASA_INTERES, MontoProvCont PROV_CONT," & _
                          "MontoProvEFEC PROV_EFEC,MontoProvTotal PROV_TOT, [%Provision]" & _
                          "FROM dbo.b_prv000_formatoNvo " & _
                          "where rut = " & Me.txtQuery.Value
         End With
     End If
End Sub
```